# In Chew, does Tony Chu ever get any diseases from the trash he eats?

Tags: comics, chew

Reading Chew #21 (Sept 2011) (which is the first I've read in the series) it shows Tony licking motor oil, human blood and other not-so-nice-on-the-stomach materials.

Is the fact that he's eating these disgusting things ever acknowledged or have any consequences on his body?

Comment: I'm glad you understand that I can't spell @Jeff lol.

Comment: I actually have an alert set up that watches for any question from you.  It then sends me a text message saying, "Prepare to spellcheck." ;-)

Comment: I've only read up to 14, but I haven't seen it happen

Comment: (I am, of course, lying.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throughout the series, Agent Chu often reacts physically (nausea, vomiting) to the things he has to consume - sometimes even at the prospect of it.

This varies by chibopath - others are fairly unphased by the consumption or partial consumption of disturbing things (e.g. one chibopath emulates Mike Tyson, another routinely consumes blood, etc.).

As far as physical consequences, chibopaths seem have little response to the consumption of toxic material.